# Как лучше доработать условие if is not None python?

Tags: python, условия, if

Всем привет ! Есть такой кусок кода.Который берет данные из БД для парсинга даты.

```
def get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
    item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
    if item_datetime is not None:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    return str(item_datetime)
```

В условии **`if itemdatetime is not none`** если `item_datetime`не пуст. Выполняется `item_datetime` иначе выполняется `item_datetime` в условии **`else`**.

Так вот,как мне сделать так чтобы в если в условии `else` не находится `datetime1_rule`.То условие пропускает это дату.И переходит к другой дате?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под словами "не находится"? Равно `None`?

Comment: Я подразумеваю,что если  на странице который происходит парсинг не найдется  правило для `datetime1_rule` то эта страница пропускается.И переходит к другой странице.Надеюсь,вы поняли.

Comment: Я бы предложил в методе возвращать `item_datetime` как есть, и если вернулось `None`, то `continue`. Я так понимаю вы страницы в цикле перебираете.

Comment: Да верно я перебираю страницы в цикле.Можете показать пример с `continue` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в код еще одно условие:

```
def get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
    item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
    if item_datetime is not None:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:
        if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
            item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]}).text
            item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
        else:
            item_datetime = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item_page in pages:
    # ...
    item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page, ...)

    if item_datetime is None:
        continue

    item_datetime = str(item_datetime)
```